# How do I allow a watchr script to be in the scope of my ActiveRecord models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, watchr

I have a watchr script running on my Ruby on Rails 3.1 app and inside the script I need to make a call like: `game = Game.find(0)` 
except whenever the script is being executed I receive this error: `uninitialized constant Watchr::Script::EvalContext::Game (NameError)`
I'm assuming that I have to require something in the beginning of the script but I'm not sure what. Incase it matters the script is located at /data/xmlwatcher.watchr

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I figured out how to do this was to put everything that deals with the database into a rake task and invoke the task with Rake::Task[].invoke. Inside of the Rake task I invoke Rake::Task['environment'] and then it works.